# Root not affected by file permissions?

Tags: permissions, root

Why does this work as root?

```
# touch test1
# chmod 000 ./test1
# echo "test" > ./test1
```

I take it root is not affected by file permissions?

Answer (score 5):

https://superuser.com/questions/104015/removing-write-permission-does-not-prevent-root-from-writing-to-the-file

This has the answer.

Root has rw on all files.
You can mark a file immutable with

```
chattr +i filename
```

removing that is

```
chattr -i filename
```

Comment: Not quite correct. Root has `rw`, but not `x` (unless it is a directory). http://sprunge.us/FNMb